# Capitalize first letter in textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, capitalize

I am using the following code to capitalize the first letter entered into a text box. This works fine at first, but if the entire box is deleted, after typing again it will not capitalize again.

Can this be fixed?

```
$(function () {
    $('.userBox').one('DOMAttrModified textInput input keypress paste focus', 
          function (e) {
             $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
                    $(this).val().slice(1));
          });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VBXbz/

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VBXbz/8/

Comment: You can use css (text-transform) [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9jB4/1/). But it will capitalise even after the full stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), not [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$(function () {
    $('.userBox').on('DOMAttrModified textInput input keypress paste focus', function (e) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().slice(1));
    });
});
```

`one` is for handlers you want executed at *most* once

Answer (score 2):

`.one` makes the event to be happen just once in the page use `.on` instead:

```
$('.userBox').on('DOMAttrModified ....
```

### updates:

you can try something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.userBox').on('DOMAttrModified  keypress',function (e) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().slice(1));
  }).on('focus',function () {
      $(this).val('');
  });
});
```